# After upgrade to OSX Mavericks: "Unable to find any JVMs matching version 1.6"

Tags: macos, mac, java

After upgrading my work notebook from Mountain Lion (10.8.5) to the Mavericks (10.9.4) this weekend, everytime I open the terminal I now get the following error message:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.6"
```

I don't have Java 6 installed, some tool that is run at the beginning of a shell session must rely on it though.

How can I find out what is the root of this problem? Please tell me if I can provide more information for troubleshooting.

Comment: What was your previous OSX version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OSX Mavericks installer removes previous installed versions of Java. You probably have a reference to Java 6 in your `.bash_profile` file (or so). It would explain the message on Terminal start-up.

Latest versions of Java (from Java 7) are directly supported by Oracle (you can find installation instructions on Java.com : [How do I install Java for my Mac](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml)).

Previous versions (Java 6 included) are supported by Apple. If you want to install Java 6, download [Java for OS X 2014-001 patch](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) directly from Apple website.

**Note :** you can find useful information about Java and Mac OS X compatibility on this [Java FAQ](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml).

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.

Comment: With me, the reference was in ~/.zprofile